# How do I split a data frame among columns, say at every nth column?

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Let's say I am working with the following data frame:

```
Mydata <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),X2 = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1),
                     X3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),X4 = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1),
                     X5 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),X6 = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1),
                     X7 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),X8 = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1),
                     X9 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),X10 = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1),
                     X11 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),X12 = c(1,3,1,1,1,5,1,1,8,1))
```

I want to split this data frame into three separate data frames, with columns X1 ~ X4 in one data frame, X5 ~ X8 in the second, and X9 ~ X12. How would I code this to continue this pattern for any number of columns?

Comment: `split.default(Mydata, ceiling(seq_along(Mydata)/4))` does the same thing, but doesn't require that you know how many columns you have

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To split `Mydata` every 4 columns. We can use explicitly use `split.default`:

```
split.default(Mydata, rep(1:3, each = 4))
```

[The "default" method can split a data frame by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738). Just set the grouping variable by your need.

---

For balanced grouping, `gl` is handy (see `?gl`). We can use `gl(3, 4)` instead of `rep(1:3, 4)` in the above, which avoids type conversion from "integer" to "factor".

In general, use `gl(ncol(Mydata) / n, n)` for "every n columns" (`n` must divide `ncol(Mydata)`).