# How to split my data frame in equal length lists

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I am working with a big data base and I am trying to chunk a balance panel in balanced panels so I can perform a `plm` loop regression.

I have been trying to divide my data frame `bb3` (balance grouping) but I can't manage to get what I want, this is my sample data `bb3` in my drive as a .RData

[bb3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VvigN-KY9sS5yUOpv8JtJW7EdJfQUFde/view?usp=sharing)

****First attempt****

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51546616/how-do-i-split-a-data-frame-among-columns-say-at-every-nth-column) I tried using `split.default` :

```
n<-6
f<-gl(n,nrow(bb3) / n )
B<-split.default(bb3, f)
```

`B` is close to what I want, but just for my first list `B[["1"]]` the other 5 lists are empty and I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In split.default(bb3, f) : data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

**TL:DR** I want to generate a list divided in 6 chunks, each with the 102 `clvs` with consecutive `date`. Even if they are not balanced, if they are consecutive I can balanced them with `make.pbalanced`. This will be my ideal solution

****Second attempt****

I generated `Index` to identify every `date` of every `clvs` (`Index` is already generated in `bb3` but for the sake of the exercise I am explaining how I did it)

```
bb3<- bb3 %>% 
  group_by(clvs) %>% 
  mutate(Index = row_number())
```

The problem is that I don't know how to split it:

```
si<-split.data.frame(bb3,bb3$Index)
```

Again `si` closely relates to what I need, it gives me a list of 551 balance list (102 `clvs` and one `date`). I want to divide `bb3` given 19 segments of `Index`.  This list (1:19,20:39,40:59,...) will determine how I divide my data frame

I am sure there should be an easy way with `function` and `lapply` but I can't come with this solution.

**TL:DR** I want to divide in 19 chunks my data frame, each chunk with 102 `clvs` each one with 29 periods `date`: a list of 19 chunks each with 2,958 observations

The solution I got by @Allan Cameron cut my data base in the size I need it but it doesn't work as a balance panel because it doesn't cut consecutive my `datetime`

```
B <- split(bb3, 1:6)
head(B[["6"]])
clvs  fecha hora    pml pml_ene pml_per pml_cng datetime date               
  <fct> <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>    <dttm>             
1 07AC~ 2017~ 6      389.    388.    1.07       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 07:00:00
2 07AC~ 2017~ 12     677.    674.    3.25       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 13:00:00
3 07AC~ 2017~ 18     667.    664.    3.15       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 19:00:00
4 07AC~ 2017~ 24     666.    664.    2.44       0 2017-03~ 2017-03-01 01:00:00
5 07AC~ 2017~ 6      664.    662.    2.05       0 2017-03~ 2017-03-01 07:00:00
6 07AC~ 2017~ 12     434.    431.    2.97       0 2017-03~ 2017-03-01 13:00:00

tail(B[["6"]])

clvs  fecha hora    pml pml_ene pml_per pml_cng datetime date               
  <fct> <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <fct>    <dttm>             
1 07XC~ 2017~ 18     430.    443.  -13.6        0 2017-03~ 2017-03-21 19:00:00
2 07XC~ 2017~ 24     418.    426.   -8.41       0 2017-03~ 2017-03-22 01:00:00
3 07XC~ 2017~ 6      442.    444.   -2.15       0 2017-03~ 2017-03-22 07:00:00
4 07XC~ 2017~ 12     451.    464.  -12.4        0 2017-03~ 2017-03-22 13:00:00
5 07XC~ 2017~ 18     450.    461.  -11.2        0 2017-03~ 2017-03-22 19:00:00
6 07XC~ 2017~ 24     452.    467.  -15          0 2017-03~ 2017-03-23 01:00:00
```

So I still can't balance my panel, nor use it with `plm`

How can I chunk it in 6 with consecutive dates?

Comment: Does your `split` work if you use `split` rather than `split.default`?

Comment: When I use `split` it doesn't give me the `Warning` message but each list has only 17 `clvs` and I need the 102 `clvs` in each list `B[[i]]`

Comment: Hi Lila I see you have unaccepted my answer. Is there a problem with it? Let me know if I can help.

Comment: Thanks for asking @AllanCameron, can you check my edit in the original post? My data frame is cutting in a no sequential date. Each list has 3 non consecutive hours for each day. I want the first 92 hours of the period (2017-02-28 1:00 to 2017-03-03 23:00) for the 102 `clvs` in the first list, then the following 92 hours in the second and ordered in chronological way, is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems like an easy task, it was very challenging splitting a balanced panel data into small balance panels.

@Allan Cameron's answer got it right in the length of the list but not the content. My panels were unbalanced, each `clvs` had 188 or 187 in the same chunk, and `datetime` was not consecutive. `B[["1"]]` had a sequence of `7:00` ,`13:00` and `19:00` for one `clvs` for example. With unbalanced panels my loop with an `splm` function didn't work.

The solution was using `gl.unequal` :

```
library(DTK)
f<-gl.unequal(n=6,k=c(92,92,92,92,92,91))
B<-split(bb3,f)
```

This way I get balanced panels, for example `B[["1"]]`

```
head(B3[["1"]])
1 07AC~ 2017~ 1      686.    684.    2.19       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 02:00:00
2 07AC~ 2017~ 2      665.    664.    1.79       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 03:00:00
3 07AC~ 2017~ 3      393.    392.    1.11       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 04:00:00
4 07AC~ 2017~ 4      383.    381.    1.4        0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 05:00:00
5 07AC~ 2017~ 5      383.    381.    1.41       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 06:00:00
6 07AC~ 2017~ 6      389.    388.    1.07       0 2017-02~ 2017-02-28 07:00:00

is.pbalanced(B[["1"]])
TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```r
B <- split(bb3, 1:6)
```

So that `B` is a list of data frames, each with 9367 rows:

```r
sapply(B, nrow)
#>    0    1    2    3    4    5 
#> 9367 9367 9367 9367 9367 9367
```

And each contains all `clvs` at roughly equal amounts:

```r
sapply(B, function(x) table(x$clvs))
#>            1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 07ACU-115 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07APD-230 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07BJO-69  92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07CAE-69  92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07CES-69  92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07CHQ-230 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07CIP-115 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07CME-115 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07CNA-69  92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07CNT-230 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07CNZ-161 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07COE-115 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07CPC-161 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07CPD-230 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07CPT-230 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07CPU-161 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07CRO-161 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07CSC-230 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07CTY-161 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07CTY-230 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07DRA-69  92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07EDA-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07END-69  92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07ENT-115 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07EPC-115 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07FCO-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07FEV-161 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07FLO-69  92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07FMO-115 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07FOR-69  91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07FTA-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07GER-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07GLL-115 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07GOR-161 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07HGO-161 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07HMO-69  91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07HUN-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07INA-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07IOP-69  92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07JAT-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07JOV-230 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07JOY-115 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07KCH-161 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07LGO-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07LMS-69  92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07LOS-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07MAB-69  92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07MEP-230 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07MEP-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07MND-115 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07MOE-161 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07MSN-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07MXC-69  92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07MXI-161 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07MXI-230 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07NEL-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07NZI-161 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07ONG-69  92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07OZA-230 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07PAF-69  91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07PAP-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07PID-161 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07PID-230 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07PJZ-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07PJZ-230 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07PKD-161 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07PNM-115 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07PNU-115 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07POP-115 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07RII-69  92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07RIN-161 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07RSI-69  91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07RUB-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07RUM-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07RZC-161 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07SAF-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07SAZ-115 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07SED-69  91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07SHA-115 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07SIO-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07SIS-161 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07SMN-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07SQN-115 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07SRY-230 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07STB-230 92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07SVE-115 92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07TCD-69  92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07TCT-69  92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07TEE-69  92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07TEK-230 91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07TJD-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07TJI-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07TOY-230 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07TRI-115 92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07UND-69  92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07VAS-69  91 92 92 92 92 92
#> 07VIG-69  92 92 92 92 92 91
#> 07VLP-69  92 92 92 92 91 92
#> 07VPA-230 92 92 92 91 92 92
#> 07VPM-69  92 92 91 92 92 92
#> 07WIS-230 92 91 92 92 92 92
#> 07XCO-230 91 92 92 92 92 92
```

And each contains 17 instances of each `datetime`:

```r
sapply(B, function(x) table(as.character(x$datetime)))
#>                      1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 2017-02-28 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-02-28 23:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 00:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-01 23:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 00:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-02 23:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 00:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-03 23:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 00:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-04 23:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 00:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-05 23:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 00:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 01:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 02:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 03:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 04:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 05:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 06:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 07:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 08:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 09:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 10:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 11:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 12:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 13:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 14:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 15:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 16:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 17:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 18:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 19:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 20:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 21:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#> 2017-03-06 22:00:00 17 17 17 17 17 17
#>  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 385 rows ]
```